# How to make div fixed in height but grows if content is bigger than height?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div to which I set `height: 500px;` in CSS, thus it's fixed in height.

The content of my page is generated automatically in JavaScript, thus sometimes it's bigger than 500px and it overflows the div border.

My question is: is it possible to have a fixed size (for example 500px) but when the div's content is greater than 500px, have the div growing bigger to contain that?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try

```
min-height: 500px;
height:auto;
```

to set a minimum height.

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Answer (score 6):

Yes

```
min-height:300px;
height:auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try this


min-height:500px;
overflow:auto;
margin:0 auto;
```