# Getting height of a div to be screen-height but extend with content

Tags: html, css

I have a div with position absolute (required) inside a container div with position absolute (required) and I want the child div to be the width of the devices screen but extend as content within it expands. Before you mark this as duplicate please note I have looked at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264124/how-can-i-make-a-div-height-automatically-fit-screen-and-expands-if-the-content) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681420/css-height-not-working-if-body-has-min-height) and many more.

my css (sass):

```
.container
  position: absolute
  overflow: visible
  width: 100%

.page
  position: absolute
  overflow: visible
  width: 100%
  min-height: 100vh
```

my HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page">
        //content
    </div>
</div>
```

With this setup, the page div does not extend with the content. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please provide a demo page?

Comment: **Duplicate question here's the solution** [How to make div fixed in height but grows if content is bigger than height?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473273/how-to-make-div-fixed-in-height-but-grows-if-content-is-bigger-than-height?rq=1

Comment: This solution does not work. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Please do not use the above link - actions get carries through to all users (browser-sync reload gulp plugin) sorry about that. use http://julienvincent.zapto.org/#/projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a third div with a min-height of 100vh, and then all the child elements go within using position: relative

css:

```
.container
  position: absolute
  overflow: visible
  width: 100%

.second-container
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  min-height: 100vh

.page
  position: absolute
  overflow: visible
  width: 100%
  min-height: 100vh
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="second-container">
            //child elements with position: relative
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `height: 100%` and `width: 100%;` to your body tag like this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then add `min-height: 100%;` to the container like this:

```
.container  {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

And finally add `height: auto;` to your child div like this:

```
.page  {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/33/

Comment: If the above is not what you want, then please elaborate a little bit more on what you're trying to do.

Comment: This solution does not work. It results in the div not showing at all. Also I do not think I need to elaborate on anything else? I have provided an example URL

Comment: Although this confuses me as it works in your jsFiddle but not on my project.

Comment: Lol You sure there aren't any css properties that might conflict with the ones I sent

Comment: I have been checking and checking again but can't find anything.

Comment: Haha ok wait up. I'll just finish up my work real quick and I'll recheck your site again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74136/discussion-between-julien-vincent-and-andrew-lyndem).